# Work with Components Independently passing some values and an Handler

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I'm having a problem with child controls, kindly provide some feedback.

For me this is confusing, I'm blocked.

First of all I have an Edit Button in a Table, this open the child or hide the main (see child code) and give me the Participant ID.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.btnListEdit', function () {
      var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
      that.setState({
        cParticipantId: data["Participant"]["Id"],
        edit: true,
      });
    });
```

The handler() to fire from child, is working and the logic for show and hide Main or Child

```
 handler() {
    this.setState({
      edit: false
    });
    this._getTableItems(initialQuery);
  }

  private handlerFilters() {
    this.setState({
      edit: false
    });
  }

......

 this.state.edit ?
            (
              <EditCert description={undefined} context={this.props.context} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handlerFilters} />
            ) : (
```

**Child Control**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const EditCert = (myprops) => {

    function ExitHandler() {
        myprops.handler();
    }
    
    return (
         <div>
              <Button onClick={ExitHandler} 
               size="small" 
               style={{ float: "right", width: "150px", marginLeft: "10px" }} 
               variant="contained" >Cancel</Button>
         </div>
    );
}
```

But the problem is I only need `mypros` to invoke the `handler()` and to be available `cParticipantId`, so this child control must work with is own State, Component chain and logic independently and I'm not using a `class` to extend `React.Component`. I can't even put a `constructor` in the child.

I really can not see how to put this working.

Comment: Instead of doing this `myprops={this.state}` try this `myProps={{handler:this.handler}}`

Comment: But the problem is the rsx of the child, how do I consume mypros with ```class EditCert  extends React.Component```